# How do I get the window geometry of top level windows excluding any decorations like shadows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, themes

I'm using the [`GetWindowRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519(v=vs.85).aspx) function to get the bounding rectangle of native windows. For top level windows, this seems to include any 'decorations' around the window such as the drop shadows which are enabled by default on Windows 10. I would like to exclude such decorations, but I do want to include the rest (e.g. the minimise/maximise button). How would (Should?) I adjust the geometry returned by [`GetWindowRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519(v=vs.85).aspx) to get this?

My first attempt was to consider the window style and then use the system metrics `CM_CxSIZEFRAME` (error handling omitted for brevity):

```
[..]
RECT r;
::GetWindowRect(handle, &r);

const bool isToplevelWindow = (::GetWindowLong(handle, GWL_STYLE) & WS_CHILD) == 0;
if (isToplevelWindow) {
    const int frameWidth = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSIZEFRAME);
    const int frameHeight = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSIZEFRAME);
    r.left += frameWidth;
    r.right -= frameWidth;
    r.top += frameHeight;
    r.bottom -= frameHeight;        
}
// process `r`
```

This seems to work *mostly* except that on the Windows 10 style, adding the frame height to the Y coordinate (i.e. `r.top`) appears to be wrong, it cuts out the top of the title bar.

By now, I noticed that not only does the `::GetSystemMetrics` functin support querying other frame metrics:

- `SM_C*DLGFRAME` (aka `SM_CxFIXEDFRAME`)
- `SM_CxFRAME` (aka `SM_CxSIZEFRAME)
- `SM_CxBORDER`
- `SM_C*PADDEDBORDER`

...there is also a 'newer' [`GetThemeSysSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759790(v=vs.85).aspx) function which provides access to some further seemingly relevant metrics.

Does anybody know which of these (if any) I should respect when trying to get rid of window decorations such as rounded edges or shadows?

Comment: Doesn't [DwmGetWindowAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969515.aspx) with a `DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS` [DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969530.aspx) return precisely the value you are looking for?

Comment: Excluding decorations like shadows, but including decorations like window borders? (Assuming Windows 10 still has window borders, and they weren't "not flat enough")

Comment: @IInspectable actually, that seems to be exactly what I was looking for! So there's yet another way to get the bounding rectangle - thanks! You should post that as an answer so that I could accept it. :-)